# In VBScript, can I raise an error to simulate Goto?

Tags: vbscript

If I were working in VBA, my current procedure would go something like this:

```
Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
arrRecord = Split(MyFile.ReadLine, ",") ' Make an array of the values in this line

'There are certain records I don't want to process:
If arrRecord(1) <> "USA" then goto skip
If arrRecord(0) <= "12/31/2001" then goto skip

' Otherwise, run the rest of the code on this record

skip:
Loop
```

But I'm working in VBScript, which doesn't have this kind of Goto function.

I'm thinking of doing the same thing by delibaratly raising an error. For instance:

```
Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
arrRecord = Split(MyFile.ReadLine, ",") ' Make an array of the values in this line

On Error Goto skip

'There are certain records I don't want to process:
If arrRecord(1) <> "USA" then Call NoSuchFunction
If arrRecord(0) <= "12/31/2001" then Call NoSuchFunction

' Otherwise, run the rest of the code on this record

skip:
Loop
```

Is there any potential problem with this? Should I use Err.Raise instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript, unlike VBA, doesn't have `On Error Goto`. It only has `On Error Resume Next`.

However, the case that you're looking for, of exiting a control flow early, can be handled with the `Exit` statement. See [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/05/04/how-can-i-exit-a-for-each-loop/) from the Microsoft Scripting Guys for more details and examples.

If you're not currently in a control flow that you are looking to exit, you can hack it by creating one that will only execute once:

```
Do
    'Stuff
    If something Then Exit Do
    'More Stuff
Loop While False 'Execute once, can be left early by "Exit Do"
```

And while that's clearly a hack, I'm not sure it's any worse than trying to use a straight "Goto" in the first place. Usually one can restructure the logic to be clear as to what one is actually doing, without needing such inelegant constructs.

Comment: That page is useful, but I'm not sure if applies in my case. I don't want to "Exit Do" altogether; I just want to jump to the next iteration of the Do loop. Is there a way to do that?  Otherwise I'd be stuck with multiple nested IF...Then loops.

Comment: The hacky way is to have a `Do`…`Loop While False` with an `Exit Do` in the middle. But you're trying to emulate a Goto, which means you're not going for the most elegant code anyway. There's usually a way to restructure things so that your control flow is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in VBScript.  The only error handling you have is `On Error Resume Next` and, to disable that within a certain scope, `On Error Goto 0`.

There's no such think as a label in VBScript.